# Discontinuity in an embedded diagram

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I am trying to plot the embedment diagram of a two-dimensional section along the equatorial plane $t =$ constant, $\theta = \pi / 2$ of a Morris-Thorne wormhole with the embed function:
$$ z(r) = \pm b_0 ln \left( r + \sqrt{(\frac{r}{b_0})^2 - 1} \right)$$
so

```
f[r_, b_Integer] := b Log[r + Sqrt[(r/b)^2 - 1]]

r1 = RevolutionPlot3D[f[r, 2], {r, 2, 50}, RevolutionAxis -> "Z", 
   SphericalRegion -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1], WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   ImageSize -> 700, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];

r2 = RevolutionPlot3D[-f[r, 2], {r, 2, 50}, RevolutionAxis -> "Z", 
   SphericalRegion -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1], WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   ImageSize -> 700, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];
Show[r1, r2, PlotRange -> All]
```

But when executing, get the graph with this jump that I can't think of how to solve

[image: Gap]

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is impssible to do this since `FunctionRange[f[r, 2], r, y] // N` is  `>0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `f` and get the desired plot effect (if I understand the question correctly):

```mathematica
f[r_, b_Integer] := b Log[r + Sqrt[(r/b)^2 - 1]] - 2 Log[2];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that in general it is true `f[r_, b_Integer] := b Log[r + Sqrt[(r/b)^2 - 1]] - b Log[b]`

Comment: except for $b = 1$

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just for visualization purposes, you can translate and reflect `r1` coordinates to remove the gap between the two pieces:

```
Show[r1, 
 MapAt[
   - #  (*reflect *)
   + 2 2 Log @ 2 (* translate *)
   &,
  {1, 1, 1, 1, All, -1}] @ r1, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]